# How do I log Pig Latin grunt shell commands that I write?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I am new to Pig and Pig Latin. I'd like to log the commands that I write in the interactive grunt shell, so that I can piece together working Pig Latin scripts. Is this possible? Is there a file that stores the history of commands I've written, similar to my ".bash_history" file?

I'd like access to the ".grunt_history", if such a thing exists, or some way to turn on logging to a file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Pig history file is in `~/.pig_history`. So, if your user home is `/home/joe`, the path is `/home/joe/.pig_history`.

However, you need to take care of locating the user home directory. You can get the user home directory from `/etc/passwd`. Some user home directory may be not standard. For example, we use the CDH4 and use **sudo -u hdfs pig** to start Grunt. In the situation, the history file is `/var/lib/hadoop-hdfs/.pig_history`. [Here](http://www.grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.pig/pig/0.11.0/org/apache/pig/Main.java#531) is the source code.

Answer (score 1):

You're close - look for `~/.pig_history`